# Google forms gets username from a spreadsheet, and then gives a unique URL for each user

Tags: url, spreadsheet, google-forms, microsoft-forms

I have users name and ID in a spreadsheet, and I want to send them Google Forms to fill out. However, I want the form to greet each user based on their names and ID from a spreadsheet, and there to be a unique URL for each user.

Finally, I would like the name and ID and other responses in the from to all be saved in a spreadsheet.

Previously, I tried to use the option to get pre-filled link which inserts the values but they can be removed by the user, and replaced with something else. Ideally, I don't want them to have to fill out their names, but I still want it to be saved into a spreadsheet. Also, apart from Google forms, does Microsoft Forms have such an option?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature to disable editing of prefilled answers.

You may need to create a web form (posting to the Google Form) with `disabled` property.

```html
<form method="post" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/XXX/formResponse"
<input id="name" name="entry.XXX" disabled>
```

```js
<script>
const params = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
name.value = params.get('name');
</script>
```